# Automatically adjust block height of <aside> to same as <main>using CSS

Tags: html, css, flexbox, overflow, css-grid

```css
body {padding: 0;margin: 0;border: 0; padding-top:48px;}
.header {height:48px; width:100%; background-color:blue; position:fixed; left:0; right:0;top:0; z-index:100;}
.container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 660px 1fr;
    grid-column-gap:10px;
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    position: relative;
    max-width: 1326px;
    margin-top:10px;
    margin-bottom:200px;
}
main {background-color:purple; height:600px; display:flex;justify-content:center; align-items:center; color:#FFF; font-size:30px;}
aside {height: calc(100vh - 48px); position: sticky; top: calc(48px + 15px);display: flex;flex-flow: column;}
aside .side-gallery {display: grid;grid-column-gap: 15px;grid-row-gap: 15px;grid-template-columns:1fr 1fr 1fr; align-items: flex-start; scrollbar-width: none; -ms-overflow-style: none;overflow-y: scroll; position: relative;max-height: 100%;padding: 0px 10px 10px;}
aside .side-gallery .item {background-color:green; width:100%; height:120px;}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="header"></div>
    <div class="container">
        <main>Need "side-gallery" (green grid) to take same height as "main content side" (purple color).</main>
        <aside>
            <div class="side-gallery">
                <div class="item"></div>
                <div class="item"></div>
                <div class="item"></div>
                <div class="item"></div>
                <div class="item"></div>
                <div class="item"></div>
                <div class="item"></div>
                <div class="item"></div>
                <div class="item"></div>
                <div class="item"></div>
                <div class="item"></div>
                <div class="item"></div>
                <div class="item"></div>
                <div class="item"></div>
                <div class="item"></div>
                <div class="item"></div>
                <div class="item"></div>
                <div class="item"></div>
                <div class="item"></div>
                <div class="item"></div>
                <div class="item"></div>
                <div class="item"></div>
                <div class="item"></div>
                <div class="item"></div>
                <div class="item"></div>
                <div class="item"></div>
                <div class="item"></div>
                <div class="item"></div>
                <div class="item"></div>
                <div class="item"></div>
                <div class="item"></div>
                <div class="item"></div>
                <div class="item"></div>
                <div class="item"></div>
                <div class="item"></div>
                <div class="item"></div>
                <div class="item"></div>
                <div class="item"></div>
                <div class="item"></div>
                <div class="item"></div>
                <div class="item"></div>
                <div class="item"></div>
                <div class="item"></div>
                <div class="item"></div>
                <div class="item"></div>
                <div class="item"></div>
                <div class="item"></div>
                <div class="item"></div>
                <div class="item"></div>
                <div class="item"></div>
                <div class="item"></div>
                <div class="item"></div>
            </div>
        </aside>
    </div>


</body>
```

Please click view "Full page" to view the code result.

I basically have 3 major elements on my website. A "fixed header" (blue color), "main content side" that always different in height size (purple color) and "side-gallery with different articles" (green color) with max-height of 100vh.

What I need: I need to make my sticky side-gallery (green color) be same height as "main content side" (purple color). Obviously I can simply set "height" of it, but since my "main content side" (purple color) is always changing, I need side-gallery (green color) to take same height automatically. Do not know how to achieve it. Only CSS solutions, please.

Answer (score 1):

I think I have been ultimately able to solve the problem :

You should remove the height property from aside element and add `flex-grow : 1` and `flex-basis: 0px` to the side-gallery .

Here is the implementation :

```css
body {padding: 0;margin: 0;border: 0; padding-top:48px;}
.header {height:48px; width:100%; background-color:blue; position:fixed; left:0; right:0;top:0; z-index:100;}
.container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 660px 1fr;
    grid-column-gap:10px;
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    position: relative;
    max-width: 1326px;
    margin-top:10px;
    margin-bottom:200px;
}
main {background-color:purple; height:400px; display:flex;justify-content:center; align-items:center; color:#FFF; font-size:30px;}
aside {position: sticky; top: calc(48px + 15px);display: flex;flex-flow: column;}
aside .side-gallery {display: grid;grid-column-gap: 15px;grid-row-gap: 15px;grid-template-columns:1fr 1fr 1fr; align-items: flex-start; scrollbar-width: none; -ms-overflow-style: none;overflow-y: scroll; position: relative;max-height: 100%;padding: 0px 10px 10px;flex-grow : 1 ;flex-basis: 0px;}
aside .side-gallery .item {background-color:green; width:100%; height:120px;}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="header"></div>
    <div class="container">
        <main>Need "side-gallery" (green grid) to take same height as "main content side" (purple color).</main>
        <aside>
            <div class="side-gallery">
                <div class="item"></div>
                <div class="item"></div>
                <div class="item"></div>
                <div class="item"></div>
                <div class="item"></div>
                <div class="item"></div>
                <div class="item"></div>
                <div class="item"></div>
                <div class="item"></div>
                <div class="item"></div>
                <div class="item"></div>
                <div class="item"></div>
                <div class="item"></div>
                <div class="item"></div>
                <div class="item"></div>
                <div class="item"></div>
                <div class="item"></div>
                <div class="item"></div>
                <div class="item"></div>
                <div class="item"></div>
                <div class="item"></div>
                <div class="item"></div>
                <div class="item"></div>
                <div class="item"></div>
                <div class="item"></div>
                <div class="item"></div>
                <div class="item"></div>
                <div class="item"></div>
                <div class="item"></div>
                <div class="item"></div>
                <div class="item"></div>
                <div class="item"></div>
                <div class="item"></div>
                <div class="item"></div>
                <div class="item"></div>
                <div class="item"></div>
                <div class="item"></div>
                <div class="item"></div>
                <div class="item"></div>
                <div class="item"></div>
                <div class="item"></div>
                <div class="item"></div>
                <div class="item"></div>
                <div class="item"></div>
                <div class="item"></div>
                <div class="item"></div>
                <div class="item"></div>
                <div class="item"></div>
                <div class="item"></div>
                <div class="item"></div>
                <div class="item"></div>
                <div class="item"></div>
            </div>
        </aside>
    </div>


</body>
```

Now the side element will dynamically change according to the main element.

Comment: Thank you, very much! This is exactly what I needed. I was thinking about `flex-basis` but was not sure where to put it. This worked perfectly!